# Electromagnetic four-potential for Kerr-Newman solution

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, black-holes, resource-recommendations, kerr-newman-metric

Any textbook or paper on the [Kerr-Newman metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr%E2%80%93Newman_metric) I found contains the solution for the electromagnetic tensor $
F^{\mu}_{\phantom{\mu} \nu}$.

Can you provide a (reliable) reference for the solution of electromagnetic four-potential $A_{\mu}$ (the derivation is not necessary)?

Comment: See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr%E2%80%93Newman_metric#Alternative_.28Kerr.E2.80.93Schild.29_formulation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the potential at the following paper -
*Furuhashi, Hironobu, and Yasusada Nambu. "Instability of massive scalar fields in Kerr-Newman spacetime." Progress of theoretical physics 112.6 (2004): 983-995.‏*
Also appear in "Black Hole Physics" by Frolov & Novikov (1997), Appendix D.

The expression (in natural units, Boyer-Lindquist coordinates) is - 
$$\boxed{\vec{A}={rQ \over r^2+a^2\cos^2{\theta}}\left(-1,0,0,a\sin^2{\theta}\right)}$$
where $a$ is angular momentum per unit mass and $Q$ is the charge of the BH.

Comment: sorry for the late comment but I don't get the dimensions of the various components. How can  $a sin^2\theta$ be dimensionless while $a^2 cos^2\theta$ has dimension of $r^2$? Here I am naively thinking that the components must have all the same dimensions but maybe this is wrong since $d\varphi$ does not have the same dimensions than $dr$...